# How to simulate a failure in testing

Tags: java, mocking

I am writing an adapter to a web service API. The adapter sync files with the web serivce. One thing I want to test is that if one sync fails while my adapter is syncing, the next sync can still pick up all the correct files.

My question is how can I simulate a failure while interacting with the real web service? For example, if the web service API contains:

```
class WebService {
    List<String> getFileNamesToSync() {
       ......
    }

    File getFile(String name) throws SomeException {
        <talks to the web service API>;
    }
}
```

And my adapter class:

```
class MyAdapter {
    void MyFunction() {
        List<String> names = webService.getFileNamesToSync();
        for(String n : names) {
            File file = webService.getFile(n);
            .......
        }
    }
}
```

How can I simulate that the third call to getFile should fail with an exception?

I understand I can achieve this via an Mock, but I still want the rest of the my calls to getFile to return real data from web service? Is this something I can achieve using a Mock? Or I have to write my own Mock class?

Comment: you can achieve this w JUnit too.

Comment: This probably isn't what you're looking for, but you could always manually throw an exception in your for loop by using a counter and throwing an Exception if counter == 3 (for example).

Comment: Can you send it an invalid request to force a failure generation like a non-existent file to get a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: JUnit is the best way simulating your process in real time. But you will need to code the JUnit Test.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Mockito, you can create an `Answer` class that keeps a counter of invocations, calls through to the real class on most calls, but when the counter reaches your magic number you throw the exception.